# How to fetch the version of software items in local machine using .net?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I need to fetch the version of adobe acrobat reader installed in local machine using .net framework 2.0 or 4.0. I tried with 'Registry' class but the problem with that is it is present as a sub key in the Registry Editor which is editable ( so it can be changed by anyone and can't assure that it is exactly the version or just the folder name) along with this it rounds off the version ( For Example: if the version is 10.1.3.23 it will be holding as 10.0). So, could anyone please let me know if there is any way to fetch the actual and full version of the reader.

I even want to know if there's any way to access the properties of the software items within the Program File using .net so that I can get all the properties of the software installed in a local machine.

Any specific advice about how to fetch the version of software items using .net, would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's with the `pg` tag?  You should update this question with relevant tags for better visiblity.  Also, are you using VB.NET or C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
   System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fileVersionObj = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Reader 9.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe");

 MessageBox.Show(fileVersionObj.FileVersion);
```

Using this you will also able to access each part of File version.

```
    MessageBox.Show(fileVersionObj.FileMajorPart.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(fileVersionObj.FileMinorPart.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(fileVersionObj.FileBuildPart.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(fileVersionObj.FilePrivatePart.ToString());
```